# Add fixed position and width to all submenus

Tags: html, css

```
<ul>
   <li> 
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The ul class submenu is position absolute which means that left: 0 starts from his ancestor, but I want a fixed place for all the ul submenus for each menu. Is there a way to tell the submenu which class to take as its ancestor so that all the ul's with submenu class will start left: 0 from another div higher then all of this, because now for every ul class submenu start from a different place (based on their ancestor)

Comment: where is your css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution may be to set `position: relative` to the parent `ul` container block.

This will set the point of reference for all absolutely positioned descendant `ul.submenu` elements.

### Demo

Your **HTML** might look like:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><span>Cats</span>
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Cat 1</li>
      <li>Cat 2</li>
      <li>Cat 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>Dogs</span>
      <ul class="submenu">
      <li>.........Dog 1</li>
      <li>.........Dog 2</li>
      <li>.........Dog 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the basic **CSS** for the layout:

```
.menu {
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.menu li span {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    outline: 1px dotted gray;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

See fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6j6Da/

Comment: yes it is relative but I dont want it to, I want it to start from the container of this code which is the nav class width fixed width.
and I want the submenus to be the same width as the nav class, because now I can change their width but they all start based on their parent menu, so the submenu of the 1 menu starts right under it, then the submenu of the 2 menu starts right under it and the place under the 1 menu is empty

Comment: I put together the basic structure of a horizontal menu with sub-menus positioned below the top level labels.  You could put a wrapper around the `.menu` block and then inherit the width, and those details depend on the rest of your layout.